# Ruby: Remove whitespace chars at the beginning of a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, whitespace

Edit: I solved this by using `strip!` to [remove leading and trailing whitespaces as I show in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef_hGfJGt3U). Then, I followed up by restoring the white space at the end of each string the array by iterating through and adding whitespace. This problem varies from the "dupe" as **my intent is to keep the whitespace at the end**. However, strip! will remove both the leading and trailing whitespace if that is your intent. (I would have made this an answer, but as this is incorrectly marked as a dupe, I could only edit my original question to include this.)

I have an array of words where I am trying to remove any whitespace that may exist at the beginning of the word instead of at the end. rstrip! just takes care of the end of a string. I want whitespaces removed from the beginning of a string.

```
example_array = ['peanut', ' butter', 'sammiches']
desired_output = ['peanut', 'butter', 'sammiches']
```

As you can see, not all elements in the array have the whitespace problem, so I can't just delete the first character as I would if all elements started with a single whitespace char.

Full code:

```
words = params[:word].gsub("\n", ",").delete("\r").split(",")
words.delete_if {|x| x == ""}
words.each do |e|
  e.lstrip!
end
```

Sample text that a user may enter on the form:

```
Corn on the cob,
Fibonacci,
StackOverflow
Chat, Meta, About
Badges
Tags,,
Unanswered
Ask Question
```

Comment: My first question is, how are you creating those arrays? By splitting some other string using substring extraction? If so, you might want to show that code and we can help fix the root cause.

Comment: Just added the full code above. :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample text as well?

Comment: No problem @Melanie. That's what we do here. Pick apart other people's code and make it sing!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`String#lstrip` (or `String#lstrip!`) is [what you're after](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001190).

```
desired_output = example_array.map(&:lstrip)
```

More comments about your code:

1. `delete_if {|x| x == ""}` can be replaced with `delete_if(&:empty?)`
2. Except you want `reject!` because `delete_if` will only return a different array, rather than modify the existing one.
3. `words.each {|e| e.lstrip!}` can be replaced with `words.each(&:lstrip!)`
4. `delete("\r")` should be redundant if you're reading a windows-style text document on a Windows machine, or a Unix-style document on a Unix machine
5. `split(",")` can be replaced with `split(", ")` or `split(/, */)` (or `/, ?/` if there should be at most one space)

So now it looks like:

```
words = params[:word].gsub("\n", ",").split(/, ?/)
words.reject!(&:empty?)
words.each(&:lstrip!)
```

I'd be able to give more advice if you had the sample text available.

**Edit**: Ok, here goes:

```
temp_array = text.split("\n").map do |line|
  fields = line.split(/, */)
  non_empty_fields = fields.reject(&:empty?)
end
temp_array.flatten(1)
```

The methods used are `String#split`, `Enumerable#map`, `Enumerable#reject` and `Array#flatten`.

Ruby also has libraries for parsing comma seperated files, but I think they're a little different between 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: Sure is! I feel like an idiot. Scanned rdocs over and over and didn't see it.

Comment: just to add ... String.strip will take care of both leading and trailing whitespaces

Comment: Or just `a.each(&:lstrip!)` if you want to modify your array in place.

Answer (score 12):

```
> ' string '.lstrip.chop
=> "string"
```

Strips both white spaces...

Comment: how about ' string '.lstrip.rstrip as .chop will remove a character from the end

Comment: for David's comment: we just can use `.strip` to get the same result of `.lstrip.rstrip` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-strip

Comment: Consider editing your answer to add an update that corrects your original answer.

Comment: `chop` will delete any character at the end, not just whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The `strip` method is mentioned in the question and some comment, but it's worth mentioning in a separate answer too. The method a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed. I think this is the most elegant method.

```
' Hello there '.strip   #=> "Hello there"
```

For info, see https://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip