# Need help breaking up Ruby code into methods

Tags: ruby, oop, methods, rspec

I am writing a program to better learn to program and I wish to use RSpec so that I can learn that as well. However, as is, the code isn't particularly RSpec friendly, so I need to break it up into methods so that I can test it.

I don't need anyone to write the code for me, but perhaps explain how I can break it up. I am new to programming and this kind of thing (breaking things up into methods) is a really difficult concept for me.

Here's what I have:

```
  if params[:url] != ''
    url = params[:url] #line created so I can return url more easily (or, in general)
    words = params[:word].gsub("\n", ",").delete("\r").split(",") #.delete redundant?
    words.reject!(&:empty?)
    words.each(&:lstrip!)
    return "#{words}", "#{url}" #so that I can return url, not sure how to do that yet
  end
```

The code is a SERP checker, it takes a url and keywords and checks their location in the search engines.

For url, it'll just be the url of the website the user wishes to check... for word, it would be the keywords they wish to check their site against in Google.. a user may fill out the input form like so:

```
Corn on the cob,
Fibonacci,
StackOverflow
Chat, Meta, About
Badges
Tags,,
Unanswered
Ask Question
```

Comment: First of all, you have an extra `end`. What is that paired with? Would you want to remove that? Next, tell us at least the purpose of the code. You put some words in the comments like 'url', but that does not make sense unless you provide a general explanation of what that code is about.

Comment: It's a SERP checker, I added that bit to the end of the OP. Also removed the extraneous end.

Comment: Can you elabolrate more on the format of `params[:url]` and `params[:word]`? What kind out input do you expect for that?

Comment: For url, it'll just be the url of the website the user wishes to check... for word, it would be the keywords they wish to check their site against in Google.. example input might be:
Corn on the cob,
Fibonacci,
StackOverflow
Chat, Meta, About
Badges
Tags,,
Unanswered
Ask Question


More information on it, on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829051/ruby-remove-whitespace-chars-at-the-beginning-of-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code takes a sloppy string and turns it into a clean array. You first clean up the string, then you polish the array. You could define methods for these actions.

```
def clean_up_words(str)
 #code to clean str
  str
end

def clean_up_list(arr)
  #code to clean arr
  arr
end

dirty_list = clean_up_words( params[:word]).split(',') 
clean_list = clean_up_list( dirty_list )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo params
  url = params[:url]
  url.empty? ? nil : [params[:word].scan(/[^\s\r,]+/), url]
end
```

- You are assigning `url = params[:url]`. If you are going to do that, you should do it before other places where you refer to the same thing to reduce the amount of calling `[]` on `param`.
- You have several conditions on the words to be extracted. (a) Either split by "\n", ",", "\r", (b) the word should not be of 0 length, (c) white characters should be stripped off. All of this can be put together as `scan(/[^\s\r,]+/)`.
- You want to return two variables when url is not empty. Use an array in that case.